# Regex not fully working

Tags: php, regex, tags

I have a special tag that i use in my pages. This tag is made up like this;

**Input:**
`{{ module : menu : params(mainmenu , index) }}`

Now the problem im having is that the second param isn't read by my regex so i cant access this param.

This is my tag im having the problems with `{{module:menu:params(mainmenu, index)}}`

```
$str = 'params(null)';

preg_match_all('{
# matches "null" in " null)"
(?<=\s)[^,]+(?=\))

|

# matches "null" in "(null)"
(?<=\()[^,]+(?=\))

|

# matches "null" in "params(null"
(?<=params\()[^,]+

|    

# matches "true" in ", true" and ""foo"" in ", "foo""
(?<=,\s)[^,]+
}x', $str, $matches);
```

And now the regex goes to work and only gives me 1 value whats in between the hooks with the params.

What PHP gives me into an array is:

```
$array = array
(
[0] => module
[1] => menu
[2] => params(mainmenu, index)
);
```

The regex is there to match the params so it gives me all the params that i give into the tag.

**Output**
Now only the first param is read and it gives me this result;

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => mainmenu
    )

)
```

**Wanted / expected output**
But i want/need this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => mainmenu
        [1] => index
    )

)
```

I hope that my explaining was good enough, if its not please comment so i can make it even more clearly.

Comment: What's your input and expected output?

Comment: Its all there. Ill put more info about this to make it more clearly for you.

Comment: You have three different inputs shown in your question. The one in your code is "params(null)". It would be great if you edited your code to show the actual input you are using.

Comment: When I change your code to have `$str = '{{module:menu:params(mainmenu, index)}}';` I get your wanted/expected output....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to get an array of  `mainmenu` and `index` strings,

```
(?<=\()[^,]*|[^\) ]+(?=\))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iR3nD8/4)

Code:

```
<?php
$data = " {{module:menu:params(mainmenu, index)}}";
$regex =  '~\w+[^,\(]+(?=[^()]*\))~';  // this is the solution that works
preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => mainmenu
            [1] => index
        )

)
```

Comment: Im not a real pro in regex but the link is amazing. Maby if i change my question its more understanding for you. I now just dont know what to do

Comment: It does work! But only when i have only 1 parameter i get problems again. And when i pur more than 2 parameters it only displays 2.

Comment: post the string which has more than 2 params in your question.

Comment: This is the string {{module:menu:params(mainmenu, index, test)}}

Comment: This is certainly how it must work, but i now cannot add special characters like dashes and stuff :$ sorry for being such a pain in the ass

Comment: Came up with a [similar one](https://eval.in/189350) to your last in comment, so won't put a new answer and plus for your last one :)